# create a many to many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users can vote on posts, so I set a many to many relationship in rails:

users have many votes
posts have many votes

posts have many users through votes
users have many posts through votes

Is there a more elegant way to create a new vote than this:

user.votes.create(:post_id => post.id).save

? thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `.save` after `create`, if all validations pass create will save the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least a "standard" way. I assume this is coming in from a form somewhere. So just pass in params like so:

```
 @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
 @vote.user = current_user
 if @vote.save
      ...
 else
      ...
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

Vote does not deserve its own entity. Just add a counter (or two) to posts model. I'd suggest following code:

```
user.votes_for(post)
```

Or in case of stackexchange platform:

```
user1.votes_up(post)
user2.votes_down(post)
```

Comment: DISAGREE. How will you control for people voting multiple times for the same post? A separate model is much safer.

Comment: True, but you could make it more universal to have "activity" model that would log creation of comments, votes or any other user generated  content.

Comment: You could, but then you would be folding vote validation logic into a "logging" class. That doesn't make too much sense either. Every time I've written a voting system I've used a separate model.